# What is c++ version of tensorrt.volume?

Tags: python, c++, nvidia, tensorrt

What is c++ alternative for this python API call:

```
...
import tensorrt as trt
size = trt.volume(input) // how to do same in c++?
...
```

**UPDATE** nvidia has C++ api, it has alternatives for all python tensorrt API calls, except this one: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-api

Comment: @SamVarshavchik except this is not a native Python library. There are many projects that provide bindings in multiple languages, like OpenCV. That’s essentially a C++ library with Python bindings, and we handle OpenCV questions mapping between Python and C++ all the time. It looks like TensorRT is a similar project. Because the Python bindings are built on top of a C++ API, there likely. *are* alternatives.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik besides, even if this were not the case there are far more constructive ways of explaining the complexities of switching to a completely different coding environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found it inside TensorRT c++ samples:

```
inline int64_t volume(const nvinfer1::Dims& d)
{
    return std::accumulate(d.d, d.d + d.nbDims, 1, std::multiplies<int64_t>());
}
```